# Handling exception logging from $window.localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I took some code for [logging angular exceptions](https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos/blob/master/modular/src/client/app/blocks/exception/exception-handler.provider.js) from a demo by John Papa.

The problem code is here:

```
function extendExceptionHandler($delegate, exceptionHandler, logger) {
    return function (exception, cause) {
        var appErrorPrefix = exceptionHandler.config.appErrorPrefix || '';
        var errorData = { exception: exception, cause: cause };

        //problem occurs when setting exception.message
        exception.message = appErrorPrefix + exception.message;

        $delegate(exception, cause);
        logger.error(exception.message, errorData);
    };
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in the debugger, I can see that `exception.message` has the value

> Failed to set the 'authorizationData' property on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'authorizationData' exceeded the quota."

However, the line `exception.message = appErrorPrefix + exception.message;` causes a second exception:

> Cannot set property message of [object Object] which has only a getter

This second message is correctly set and the logger now works. So why can't I set the `exception.message` property when the first exception is thrown? (it is thrown by a call to `$window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);`)

Answer (score 0):

The *exception.message* that is thrown to your exception handler seems to be "read only". I don't have any documentation to back that (might be one of those every-browser-does-it-differently things), but an easy test would be to use a local variable for the logged message. Since you are only logging and delegating, this might be all you need.